# What are the ways to validate the hypothesis in Data Science with Python?

Tags: python, data-science, hypothesis-test

I want to validate the some given hypothesis over the provided data. Please share the available python libraries details which can help to validate the hypothesis. And it would be a great help, if somebody aware of the steps by which we can do hypothesis validation with python in general.

Comment: this is a Question-Answers website about programming. try wikipedia instead

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into hypothesis testing and binomial distribution. It's all further education level mathematics/statistics, so nothing too difficult.

Comment: Can you please share some website tutorials link by which I can get such info?

Comment: @Himmat https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/significance-tests-one-sample/idea-of-significance-tests/v/simple-hypothesis-testing